# Access query to count records meeting criteria

Tags: ms-access, count

I have used Excel for a long time and am now trying to make the big switch to Access. I am trying to count how many records from a table meet certain demographic criteria (3 fields- region, sex, and race). I would like to repeat this for 36 times for all the possibilities from another field. Is there any way to expedite this process? Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us more details about what this means: *"I would like to repeat this for 36 times for all the possibilities from another field."*  It may help to show us sample data and the output you want based on those data.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Select Religion, Sex, Race, Sum(1) as RecCount
From MyTable
Where Religion = "Whatever" and Sex = "Whatever" and Race = "Whatever"
Group By Religion, Sex, Race
```

You may have to use the HAVING clause instead of the WHERE clause, but given the vagueness of your question that's the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where would I type in "Sum(1)"? Is that on a query? To clarify my original question, let's say I have a table with 3 fields, and each field has 2 choices. There are 8 unique combinations, and I want to get a count of how many records there are for each of those 8 combinations.